# Is there a reason this JavaScript is not displaying?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making this code assignment, and when I went to validate it, it seems the JavaScript wasn't being "called." So I checked my code. The HTML elements call the JavaScript okay, there are no typos, and I still haven't found the problem!

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Conditional statements and Loops</title>
</head>
    
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pattern_javascript.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function loop() {
var asterisk = ["*", "**", "***", "****", "*****", "******", "*******", "********"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < asterisk.length; i++) {
text += asterisk[i] + "<br>";
}
}

loop()
```

Comment: You don't do anything with text, you aren't displaying it in anyway.

Comment: You're storing a string in a variable. You aren't doing anything that would make it display anywhere.

Comment: where do you show text?

Comment: I thought the text += would do it, no?

Comment: you are only appending the text to a string variable, without outputting it

Comment: @amateur_coder No, it wouldn’t. Something like `console.log(text);` would (if you were to replace `<br>` by `\n`). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and see your output there. If you want to output it in HTML, use `document.body.innerHTML = text;`. Try figuring out where to put one of these lines of codes yourself; you want to output this when you call the `loop` function, so it must be in the `loop` function body, but not every iteration, so outside `for`, but after the string is finished. So where do you put it?

Comment: where would I place console.log(text);? @user4642212

Comment: @amateur_coder Reread my updated comment above.

Comment: Ok, I tried google inspect

Comment: It appears that my document isnt finding any javascript

Comment: I'll send screenshots

Comment: @amateur_coder Please [edit] your question if you’re going to provide screenshots.

Comment: Ok, nevermind the screenshots. Google is saying 0 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of text is being generated properly. However you need to use the text somewhere in the html

```
function loop() {
var asterisk = ["*", "**", "***", "****", "*****", "******", "*******", "********"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < asterisk.length; i++) {
text += asterisk[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
}

loop()
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Conditional statements and Loops</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pattern_javascript.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid

Comment: With another user marking document.write as obsolete, I mark this the correct answer.

Comment: @amateur_coder None of the answers mention `document.write`.

Answer (score 1):

You define and populate several local variables, then discard them all without displaying anything. You possibly want a `return` statement:

```js
function loop() {
  var asterisk = ["*", "**", "***", "****", "*****", "******", "*******", "********"];
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < asterisk.length; i++) {
    text += asterisk[i] + "<br>";
  }
  return text; // <------------
}

document.querySelector("section").innerHTML = loop();
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Comment: Hey! I found a solution, and I am marking this the correct answer since it is similar. I replaced the console.log with a document.write and it is now displaying. Thank you!

Comment: @amateur_coder `document.write` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/4642212) for DOM manipulations, as it is obsolete, slow and not suitable for any evolving application.

Comment: This code does not satisfy the question asked here, As the user needs the text to be displayed on the HTML and not on the console.

Comment: @user4642212 ok, I will try the other users answer.

Comment: @KarthikRadhakrishnan The question didn't state anything like that. Such new requirement was made afterwards in some followup comments. I'll update the answer anyway.